# Angular 2 Typescript Pipes Filter not working

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

**i want to search *ngFor values through searchtext ngModel textbox,i'm binding ngFor from dexie indexeddb wrapper. 
            while running my program i get some errors , erros are below please check this and help me.**

**Search.html Page:**

```
    <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchtext" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-info" type="button">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                </div>
             </div>
            <br>
            // here i'm using pipe filter
            <div class="card" *ngFor="let group of listgroups | filter: searchtext">
            <div class="card-header card-default col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><a>&nbsp;{{ group.GroupID }}</a> 
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
            <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-user card-text card-default col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">&nbsp;
                {{ group.GroupName }} </p>
            </div>
            </div>
```

**component.ts page:**

```
    import { Component,Pipes,PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    import { SearchGroupService } from 'app/Services/searchgroup.service';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { FilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';


    @Component({
        selector : 'search',
        templateUrl : 'app/Views/searchgroup.html',
        pipes: [FilterPipe],
        providers: [SearchGroupService]
    })

    export class SearchGroupComponent implements PipeTransform { 
        id: id = [];
        x: any;
        name: name = [];
        totalcount: any;
        constructor(public rotuer: Router){
        //  this._searchgroupservice.getGroupService();private _searchgroupservice: SearchGroupService
         //  console.log(this._searchgroupservice.BindGroupDetails());
       //   this._searchgroupservice.BindGroupDetails();
         // this.router = Router;
        //  var _this = this;
        //  this.router = router;

      }
```

**filter.pipe.ts page**

```
    import { Pipe,PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
        name: 'filter'
    })

    export class FilterPipe implemnts PipeTransform{

        transform(listgroups:any, searchtext:any):any {
            var searchtext = this.searchtext;
            var listgroups = this.listgroups;
            if(searchtext === undefined) return listgroups;

            return listgroups.filter(function(listgroups){
                return listgroups.GroupID.toLowerCase().includes(searchtext.toLowerCase()); 
            })
        }
    }
```

**Errors:**

```
    TypeScript transpiling to CommonJS, consider setting module: "system" in typescriptOptions to transpile directly to System.register format npmcdn.com/plugin-typescript@4.0.10/lib/logger:20
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/…nesh/Project/AngType_20161017/Test%20Old/www/app/Components/filter.pipe.ts
    Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/Users/admin/Desktop/Dinesh/Project/AngType_20161017/Test%20Old/www/app/Components/filter.pipe.ts
        Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/Users/admin/Desktop/Dinesh/Project/AngType_20161017/Test%20Old/www/app/Components/filter.pipe.ts
            at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/Users/admin/Desktop/Dinesh/Project/AngType_20161017/Test%20Old/www/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:203:28)
            at Zone.runGuarded (http://127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/Users/admin/Desktop/Dinesh/Project/AngType_20161017/Test%20Old/www/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:110:47)
            at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/Users/admin/Desktop/Dinesh/Project/AngType_20161017/Test%20Old/www/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:86:29)
        Error loading http://127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/Users/admin/Desktop/Dinesh/Project/AngType_20161017/Test%20Old/www/app/Components/filter.pipe.ts as "./filter.pipe" from http://127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp`enter code here`/x/C/Users/admin/Desktop/Dinesh/Project/AngType_20161017/Test%20Old/www/app/Components/searchgroup.component.ts**
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies with this line:

`import { SearchGroupService } from 'app/Services/searchgroup.service';`

Here you import a file that doesn't start with either `./` or `../` which indicates that you mean to import a module but no module exists with this name.

Because this file is missing (see the 404 status) things go south when loading the application.

***Edited answer***

It appears that SystemJS cannot find the filter.pipe.ts file in the Components directory. Are you sure this is where the file is? If not, your import is incorrect.

In your component you have this import:

```
import { FilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';
```

This implies that the `filter.pipe.ts` is in the `Components` folder next to the component. But SystemJS is complaining that it cannot find the file there. I assume you have your Pipe in something like a `Pipes` folder, which would mean the import would be something like this:

```
 import { FilterPipe } from '../Pipes/filter.pipe';
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: i removed service from that page,

Comment: i removed service from that ts file:

Comment: Please give solution to search *ngFor values through searchtext ngModel textbox

Comment: https://youtu.be/sVTNaYBVP88 i refer this video to create code. better you see the video give solution sir.

Comment: This issue has little to do with Angular2. Let me ask you this, what is the full path of the filter.pipe.ts file on disk?

Comment: app/filter.pipe.ts

Comment: Exactly, the url that is requested looks for it in app/Components/filter.pipe.ts, you should change the import in searchgroup.component.ts to import { FilterPipe } from '../filter.pipe'; (note the two dots in ../)

Comment: brother you have any sample code for my problem(pipes to search values on ngFor).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't, sorry I wasn't able to help you more